# Two java objects, same native address?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I have native method like this.

```
public native int NativeMethod(Object object);

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL  NativeMethod(
    JNIEnv *,
    jobject,
    jobject object) {
   printf("%d", (int)object);
}
```

I call the method two times with different Java objects.

In Java I output their `hashCode()` and `toString()` info and they have different values.

But in native C, they have same output value.

It is just observed on Android 5.x devices and working well on devices below 5.0.
Also it works first time(different value in C) and doesn't work after that(some operations, not specific).

Really I don't how to fix it.
Anyone can help? Please.

Comment: *But in native C, they have same output value.* what have same output? `printf("%d", (int)object);` ? **If so, why do you bother about this?** maybe it is the same place at the memory where passed value from java are copied ... it should be valid in `NativeMethod` scope ... if you wana use it outside this scope then the question is:  are you using NewGlobalRef? (are you stashing a reference without ensuring it’s global?)

Comment: Thanks Selvin.
Yes, printf("%d", (int)object);" has same output.

Comment: Because I need send the jobjects to a third party API and the API will not create new instace depending on the jobject for the second time if the second jobject has  the same address with the first one.You mean I need to NewGlobalRef(jobject) and send the GlobalRef to the third API? I'll try, thank you very much..

Comment: It works well.Thanks. How to mark it as an answer?